# Changing themes on locally hosted webpages

Tags: themes, localhost, ftp, local-installation

I recently turned my Raspberry Pi into a web server, and now I installed Wordpress on it. Everything is going excellently, but when I went to change the theme from default, I found I need my hostname, FTP username, and FTP password. I didn't see this as a major problem, so since I host my webpage on my 'Pi I put in "localhost" and my MySQL username/password for the server I set up.

It popped up an error saying it failed to connect to the FTP server. Since I am still fairly new to Wordpress and webhosting, could someone please tell me what I *should* have used?

Comment: you should use the FTP user/password, not the mysql.

Comment: @MarkKaplun And what FTP is that? When I created this, I did not use an FTP.

Comment: How did you install wordpress? you should be able to install any theme in the same way if you have access to the file system. The FTP way is just a convenient way to install things from the webserver but it depends on having an FTP server as well, something that all shared hosting have. So you can instal an FTP server to make the install work the way you tried it, but you don't have to use that method.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I used the BI terminal in Raspberry Pi to set it up. Anyway, I worked around it by downloading the themes I wanted and moving them into the wp-content/themes folder. Now, I'm having a completely different issue. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161051/wordpress-running-on-rasppi-not-displaying-themes-correctly?noredirect=1#comment232826_161051